# Rails: Which controller is my page using?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing, formbuilder

On this page...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

... in section 1.3 it says:

*When the form is submitted, the name will be passed along with the form data, and will make its way to the params hash in the controller with the value entered by the user for that field.*

The form I'm trying to add is on a page (with a view) called 'whattypeofleaderareyou.html.rb'. How do I tell which controller is being used? Is that dependent on how the user got to the page? (ie, the last URL request?).

I know this is probably not at all helpful, but the button that takes you to this page has the html:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/whattypeofleader">next</a>
```

But that obviously doesn't tell me much about which controller is used for the page with the form.

I realise there must be something fundamental I'm not getting about this, but could someone please take the time to point out what it is, and ideally explain it?

I should add that I have repeatedly checked 'rake routes' but I think there's some meaning about the list of routes mapped to paths that I don't appreciate. I suspect the list of routes to paths is significant, but I don't understand its **meaning**. If someone could explain that, that would also be great.

Comment: It's in your config/routes.rb I believe

Comment: OK, thanks for this. I can see it's using the Home controller and the whattypeofleaderareyou action (which I'm guessing isn't the best action name). I may have to ask yet another question to get at which action on the Home controller is called when the user clicks submit - unless you have any ideas...

Comment: The answer below got me to check the output from the command line server. When I click the submit button it uses the User controller and the show action. I'm assuming this is because I pass the form_for the current user. Please let me know if I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [run `rake routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes) to get a listing of the available routes and the controller they match.

If the application is running and you know the URL you want to find the matching controller, when you run `rails s` you can see in it's output which controller's method is executing:

```
Started GET "/answers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 11:45:10 -0300
Processing by AnswersController#index as HTML
  Answer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" 
  Rendered answers/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 88ms (Views: 68.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

You see the request was `GET /answers`, and was attended by `AnswersController`'s `index` method here.

Comment: My application GETs /users/ and an id. I'm guessing this is because I pass form_for the current user. It then runs the show action on the User controller. I may need to ask another question about how to direct my application to a 'results' page instead. And I am aware of rake routes, but I don't have a clear idea of when a route is called. I know that routes are mapped to paths, but not when any specific route might 'happen'. If you could explain that, that would be great. Thanks.